Log out Terminal command to sign out from Microsoft Apps?
Looking for a command that I can put in a script so every time the screen locks in a mac, it automatically logs out from Microsoft Apps (word, powerpoint, teams...), log out from zoom and clear browser's cache.
for app in "Microsoft Word" "Microsoft Excel" "Microsoft PowerPoint"; do
    if pgrep -x "$app" > /dev/null; then
        osascript -e "quit app \"$app\""

This is what I did but it just quits the app. Doesn't log out

Maybe something like tell app \"$app\" to logout?

What does it mean to logout from Word? It's not an online client.

This Q seems more appropriate for [apple.se]. Delete here and repost there. Good luck.
